# Javascript object is in array but can't access it

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object

I have a for loop which iterates through currentObject in response.

This code:

```
console.log(response[currentObject]);
```

Clearly shows that response[currentObject] has among other properties, "start".

However, this code tells me the variable is undefined:

```
console.log(response[currentObject].start);
```

Why is this? Note that "start" is a date variable.

Here is the whole function:

```
function(response) {

                            for (var currentObject in response) {
                                //Parsing the data before its used
                                //"17\/10\/2012 20:55:00"
                                var phpStartDate = response[currentObject].start;
                                console.log(response[currentObject]);
                                var phpStopDate = response[currentObject].stop;
                                var datePartsStart = phpStartDate.match(/(\d+)/g);
                                var datePartsStop = phpStopDate.match(/(\d+)/g);
                                var parsedDateStart = new Date(datePartsStart[2], datePartsStart[1], datePartsStart[0], datePartsStart[3], datePartsStart[4], datePartsStart[5]);
                                var parsedDateStop = new Date(datePartsStop[2], datePartsStop[1], datePartsStop[0], datePartsStop[3], datePartsStop[4], datePartsStop[5]);

                                response[currentObject].start = parsedDateStart;
                                response[currentObject].stop = parsedDateStop;
                                //debugger;
                            };
                            return response;
                        }
```

Forgot to add, I'm using jQuery 1.8.2, which I believe handles dates differently than 1.7 (but I can't use 1.7 because I had a whole bunch of other problems with it!)

Here is the output of console.log(response):Object

```
data: Array[3]
0: Object
hourly: "4.00"
id: "40"
staff: "James Hadley"
start: "2012-09-25 00:00:00"
stop: "2012-09-27 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
hourly: "25.00"
id: "39"
staff: "James Hadley"
start: "2012-10-17 21:12:00"
stop: "2012-10-26 02:30:00"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
total: 3
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: So the response is JSON? Could you show the response, and the output of `typeof response`?

Comment: Yes it's JSON. typeof shows Object. I'm editing the above with "response" now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a timing issue, because the console.log object is *live*. Try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response[currentObject]));
```

I bet it does NOT include `start` even thought without `stringify` it does. Your response is asynchronous and you access `start` too early (your code doesn't show that part).

Now with your comment it's obvious. It's an array and you are missing and index, e.g. 0.

```
console.log(response[currentObject][0].start);
```

Comment: [{"id":"40","start":"2012-09-25 00:00:00","stop":"2012-09-27 00:00:00","hourly":"4.00","staff":"James Hadley"},{"id":"39","start":"2012-10-17 21:12:00","stop":"2012-10-26 02:30:00","hourly":"25.00","staff":"James Hadley"},{"id":"37","start":"2012-12-20 00:00:00","stop":"2012-12-20 00:00:00","hourly":"25.00","staff":"James Hadley"}]

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

use

> currentObject.start = parsedDateStart

instead of

> response[currentObject].start = parsedDateStart

Comment: `currentObject` is the key (awful name, i know), not the value, so this would not work.